# How to communicate with multiple clients in a UDP server in go?

Tags: go, udp

I have a server that transfers files over UDP and it works well when with only one client at the time, but if other client tries to connect, the following error is thrown

> listen udp :20000: bind: Only one usage of each socket address
>   (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.

This is my code in main:

```
...
fmt.Println("Input the number of connections")
var number int
fmt.Scanln(&number)

var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(number)

lAdd, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", PORT)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}

for i:=0; i < number; i++ {
    go startConnection(lAdd, file, i, wg)
}
wg.Wait()
```

This is the code of startConnection:

```
func startConnection (lAdd * net.UDPAddr, archivo string, i int, wg sync.WaitGroup) {

defer wg.Done()

conn, err := net.ListenUDP("udp", lAdd)
if err != nil {
    logger.Println("There was an error: ", err)
    return
}

defer conn.Close()

sendFile (conn, add, archivo, i)
}
```

Comment: you don't "accept" UDP clients, you just read packets from the socket. Don't call `listenUDP` more than once per address.

Comment: I know that UDP is not connection oriented, but I didn't knew which other word to use so is easy to understand the problem. Each client has a different address.

Comment: You don't need more than one socket. It isn't TCP.

Answer (score 0):

A server should call `Listen` only once to start the listener. At that point, it is listening. This is where TCP and UDP diverge, because of the nature of the protocols.

`ListenTCP` returns a `TCPListener`, which can be used to `Accept` connections as they come in. Each connection can then send and receive data.

`ListenUDP` returns a `UDPConn`, the same as `DialUDP`, because UDP is a connectionless protocol. You just read and write to the `UDPConn`. UDP packet headers include the source and target information, so you can use `ReadFrom` to read data and see who sent it, and `WriteTo` to respond to a specific client.

[This article (saved by archive.org)](https://web.archive.org/web/20220713034819/https://ops.tips/blog/udp-client-and-server-in-go/) has a pretty thorough rundown of implementing UDP connectivity in Go.

Comment: If you're going to mention `DialUDP`, It should be noted that it creates a "connected UDP" socket, and the kernel will filter out any packets that don't match the dialed address so that recv works correctly. This means it won't work correctly in this use case with many remote clients sending packets to the same socket ( I can't recall offhand the behavior of `WriteTo` in this situation. I wouldn't be surprised by any possible behavior here)

Comment: Yes. `ListenUDP` is the correct method for establishing a UDP listener (aka server), hence the name.

Comment: That ops.tips site is no more :(

Comment: @AleksandrPanzin https://web.archive.org/web/20220713034819/https://ops.tips/blog/udp-client-and-server-in-go/